# How to do paginate in Laravel?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, pagination, laravel-4

so what i want is to use paginate in my view but i got always an error `Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object`, this is my code :

**First my Action :**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $logs = DB::table('services')
                ->join('logs', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('services.id', '=', 'logs.service_id');
            })
            ->get()->paginate(10); //here i got the error

        return View::make('logs.index',array('logs'=> $logs,'title'=>'Service Logs'));
    }
```

**Then my view :**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Domain</td>
        <td>Port</td>
        <td>Checktime</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Responce</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<div class="container">
@foreach($logs as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $value->domain }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->service_port }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->checktime }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            @if( $value->status == 'up' ) <img src="../img/up3.png" />
            @elseif( $value->status == 'down' ) <img src="../img/down3.png" />
            @else <img width="30" height="30" src="../img/warning_icon.png" />
            @endif
        </td>
        <td>{{ $value->response_time }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
   </div>
   </table>
   {{$logs->links();}}
```

So please if someone has any idea i will be so appreciative

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use `get` when you are using pagination. Your query should simply be:

```
$logs = DB::table('services')->join('logs', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('services.id', '=', 'logs.service_id');
        })->paginate(10);
```

In fact you can remove that closure as well since this really isn't a complex join.

```
$logs = DB::table('services')
          ->join('logs', 'services.id', '=', 'logs.service_id')
          ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Voted +1, I know I can't compete with Jason Lewis! Thanks man for the work you are doing for the Laravel Community

Comment: Thanks Jason it works but how can i get the pagination in my view ?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs (http://laravel.com/docs/pagination) it seems that the correct usage is:

```
$logs = DB::table('services')
    ->join('logs', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('services.id', '=', 'logs.service_id');
    })
    ->paginate(10); //removed get()
```